# Which collections $\{g_n\}$ of continuous functions satisfy $\int_{0}^{1} f \cdot g_n = 0$ implies $f \equiv 0$ for any continuous $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, approximation

What is a characterization of (linearly independent) collections $\{g_n\}_{n \geq 1} \subset C[0,1]$ with the following property: $$\left(f \in C[0,1] \ \text{and} \ \int_{0}^{1} f(x)g_n(x) \ dx = 0 \ \text{for each} \ n=0,1,2 \cdots\right) \ \text{implies} \ f \equiv 0$$

A sufficient condition is that $\{g_n\}_{n \geq 1}$ spans a dense subset of $C[0,1]$, but is this also necessary?

This question is motivated by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381446/assume-f-is-continuous-on-1-1-if-int-11fxxndx-0-for-all-non?noredirect=1&lq=1) classic problem.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood the setting properly but what if you take $\{g_n\}$ not dense, and $f$ not in the closure? Then you have no information about $\int_0^1 f f$ which would mean density in necessary.

Comment: @Korf I see what you mean, but how do you formalize "no information about $\int_{0}^{1} \ f f$"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a set $A\subset C([0, 1])$, write 
$$
A^\bot:=\left\{ f\in C([0, 1])\ : \int_0^1 fg\, dx=0, \ \forall g\in A\right\}.$$ 
Now, let $G=\{g_n\ :\ n\in\mathbb N\}$; your question is rewritten as follows.

> What conditions guarantee that $G^\bot=\{0\}$?

This notation strongly hints at Hilbert space theory. Indeed, since $$A^{\bot \bot}= \overline{\operatorname{span } A},$$ 
where $\overline{\operatorname{span}A}$ denotes the closure in $L^2(0, 1)$ of the linear span of $A$, we have that 
$$
G^\bot=\{0\} \quad \iff \quad \overline{\operatorname{span } G}= \{0\}^\bot=L^2(0, 1).$$

> The sought condition is, thus, that $\operatorname{span}G$ is dense in $L^2(0, 1)$.

Since $C([0, 1])$ is itself dense in $L^2(0, 1)$, it suffices to check that $\operatorname{span}G$ is dense in $C([0, 1])$, **but with respect to the $L^2$ norm**.

**Final remark**. Usually, it is more difficult to prove that $\operatorname{span}G$ is dense than to prove that $G^\bot=\{0\}$.